# Replace function query

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

One column of my query output contains char 13 ( new line character). To replace it with nothing I am trying to use below function but it is giving me below error ORA-00936: missing expression

```
select
replace(AUDITOR_COMMENTS,char(13),'')  
from csa_sli_all.T_CONV_QUOTE
```

When I put char(13) in quote 'char(13)' error goes but it will not do as desired.
I think I cannot include char(13) in quotes .
I am using Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 6):

The function isn't char it's chr try calling:

```
select
replace(AUDITOR_COMMENTS,chr(13),'')  
from csa_sli_all.T_CONV_QUOTE
```

Answer (score 1):

try chr(13) instead of char(13) and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(your_data, chr(13), '')
```

try this as @sebastian said

```
select
replace(AUDITOR_COMMENTS,chr(13),'')  
from csa_sli_all.T_CONV_QUOTE
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268860/trim-whitespaces-new-line-and-tab-space-in-a-string-in-oracle    and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407027/pl-sql-replace-function-isnt-handling-carriage-returns-line-feeds

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> > REPLACE(col_name, CHR(13) + CHR(10), '')

or

> REPLACE(REPLACE( col_name, CHR(10) ), CHR(13) )

Comment: Hi...
Carriage returns = 13 ; Line Feeds = 10 ;
I just thought replacing the both would work.. and fortunately, it worked.. :)