# How to handle string with only space in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a case where I am getting the data from DB and converting the string to a number using TO_NUMBER, but this case fails when the string is an empty string with unknown or space char like

```
columnA
------
  4444
      
333333
```

The string '4444' and '333333' is converted to number by there is and error "ora-01722 invalid number" for the 2nd string.

Can this be handled with DECODE or CAST in any way, because I need to use TO_NUMBER any how for further processing?

Comment: look at TRIM and NVL functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this could be Insight of your issue.

```sql
select 
    TO_NUMBER(trim(colA)),  
    TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(colA,'(^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$)')),
    regexp_instr(colA, '[0-9.]')    
from 
(
    select '   123' colA from dual
    union all
    select '   ' colA from dual
    union all
    select '.456' colA from dual
)
```

This is similar issue : [Trim Whitespaces (New Line and Tab space) in a String in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268860/trim-whitespaces-new-line-and-tab-space-in-a-string-in-oracle/2274942)

Answer (score 0):

- If all the data within that column is composed of integers, integers with leading and/or trailing whitespaces, null values and only whitespaces then only using `TRIM()` function will suffice such as

```sql
SELECT TRIM(columnA)
  FROM t
```

and that would be more performant than using functions of regular expressions

**But**

- If the data contains decimal numbers, letters, punctiations and special characters along with whitespaces and null values, then use

```sql
SELECT TRIM('.' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(columnA,'[^[:digit:].]'))
  FROM t
```

where there is at most one dot character assumed to be between the starting and ending digits. All of the leading and trailing dots are trimmed at the end of the operation provided there is any of them. The other characters are already removed by the regular expression.

- If you're sure that there's no trailing or leading dots, then using

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(columnA,'[^[:digit:].]')
  FROM t
```

would be enough

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2fa2bf4f73a174158f8b207c06b5d56a)</kbd>

*You can wrap up any of the expressions with `TO_NUMBER()` function depending on your case at the end*

Comment: In `[^[:digit:].[:digit:]]` the second `[:digit:]` is redundant and can be removed as you have already got it once in the character list.

Comment: "redundant" depends on the case. For the third case I've used only one `[:digit:]` POSIX but used twice for the second one. Since there might exist leading and/or trailing dots for the second case as it has no restriction for the character sets @MT0 Check out the demo please.

Comment: See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e26d14e783c4eff705185bae8cb1f6fb) `[]` is the syntax for a character list and matches a **SINGLE** character; it does not match a sequence of characters. In this case you are matching a single character that is not either a digit or a dot or a digit and you don't need to check for digit twice.

Comment: Thank you, good catch! @MT0 I presume you wanted to recommend `TRIM('.' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(columnA,'[^[:digit:].]'))` for `case_b_simple` rather than the current one.

Comment: No, I'd be using a `NUMBER` column rather than getting into the situation where you need to parse badly formatted strings; if that isn't possible then I'd be using `REGEXP_SUBSTR(columnA, '\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+')` to find the first decimal value and ignore everything else (however the OP's question is not clear on their requirements if there were decimals). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d97c22f68fd926dbd6efef27a4a26ff8)